# PHP If Statement with Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a variable`$var`.

I want echo `"true"` if `$var` is equal to any of the following values `abc`, `def`, `hij`, `klm`, or `nop`. Is there a way to do this with a single statement like `&&`??

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
if($var == "abc" || $var == "def" || ...)
{
    echo "true";
}
```

Using "Or" instead of "And" would help here, i think

Answer (score 139):

An elegant way is building an array on the fly and using `in_array()`:

```
if (in_array($var, array("abc", "def", "ghi")))
```

The [`switch` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is also an alternative:

```
switch ($var) {
case "abc":
case "def":
case "hij":
    echo "yes";
    break;
default:
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: I swear in php3 I used to do if($var == 'abc'|'xyz'|'cbs')
maybe it was just a dream :p

Comment: How about multiple and `&&`?

Answer (score 16):

you can use in_array function of php

```
$array=array('abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm', 'nop');

if (in_array($val,$array))
{
  echo 'Value found';
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Dont know, why you want to use `&&`. Theres an easier solution

```
echo in_array($var, array('abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm', 'nop'))
      ? 'yes' 
      : 'no';
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use the boolean operator or: ||

```
if($var == 'abc' || $var == 'def' || $var == 'hij' || $var == 'klm' || $var == 'nop'){
    echo "true";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```php
echo (($var=='abc' || $var=='def' || $var=='hij' || $var=='klm' || $var=='nop') ? "true" : "false");
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to resurrect this, but I stumbled across it & believe it adds value to the question.

In **PHP 8.0.0^** you can now use the match expression like so:

```php
echo match ($var) {
    'abc','def','hij','klm' => 'true',
}

// echos 'true' as a string
```

[Working link from OnlinePHPfunctions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31ad84a6fba9dc06a994ab54a7e871e61ce63b94)

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)

Comment: You will also need `default => 'false'` with your match cases, otherwise an exception `UnhandledMatchError` is thrown for any value not in the list.

Answer (score 5):

I found this method worked for me:

```
$thisproduct = "my_product_id";
$array=array("$product1", "$product2", "$product3", "$product4");
if (in_array($thisproduct,$array)) {
    echo "Product found";
}
```

Comment: `in_array()` was recommended 7 years earlier.  This code-only answer adds no new value to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
$first = $string[0]; 
if($first == 'A' || $first == 'E' || $first == 'I' || $first == 'O' || $first == 'U') {
   $v='starts with vowel';
} 
else {
   $v='does not start with vowel';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to use array and compare each value 1 by 1 in loop. Its give advantage to change the length of your tests array. Write a function taking 2 parameters, 1 is test array and other one is the value to be tested.

```
$test_array = ('test1','test2', 'test3','test4');
for($i = 0; $i < count($test_array); $i++){
   if($test_value == $test_array[$i]){
       $ret_val = true;
       break;
   }
   else{
       $ret_val = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -9):

I don't know if $var is a string and you want to find only those expressions but here it goes either way.

Try to use preg_match http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
if(preg_match('abc', $val) || preg_match('def', $val) || ...)
   echo "true"
```

Comment: -1 Wow! Do you know how much overhead you just caused? Good god, man!

Comment: Not to mention the missing delimiters in in the pattern.