# How to have multiple conditions on the same if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php if statement with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593512/php-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

```
$style = get_option('background_style');
if ($style == "option1") {
    echo '<div class="background-style1">';
}
```

This is what I've got if I want "option 1" to echo the div class .background-style1, but I'm wondering how I could list more options after "option 1".

I've tried this:

```
if ($style == "option1", "option2", "option3")
```

But it doesn't work. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: There is no need to put `<?php` in the code snippet. The question is tagged [tag:php], we all know it is PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($style == 'option1' or $style == 'option2' or $style == 'option3') {
    // do something...
}
```

This is the most basic way to include multiple conditions in an if statement, you can also use other logical operators. for more info see here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 4):

```
if (in_array($style, array("option1", "option2", "option3")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your actual requirement.

If you want the same div to be displayed for option 1, 2 and 3 :

```
 if ($style == "option1" || $style == "option2" || $style == "option3")
```

If you want to address each condition separate, go for a switch statement as mentioned by @Freethinker.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a switch statement.

```
switch($style)
{
    case 'option1':
    // code for option 1;
    break;
    case 'option2':
    // code for option 2;
    break;
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/^option[1-3]$/', $style)) {
```

Comment: Hello @Barmar sir, can you help me out in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834568/how-to-call-json-from-multiple-nested-if-condition