# How to call json from multiple nested if condition

Tags: php, jquery, json, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am working on the small project which is a Batch list. Now If an admin wants to create the batch list then should enter the start date and end date and start time and end time then it will check in the database that batch is running on the same date and time? If yes then it will display the message if not then it will create a new batch list.

If the date is the same the time should be different.

Now My logic is,
I am comparing the first new_start_date with exist_start_date and exist_end_date if date found in between then it will check the time.

It's working till date compare. Even it's checking the time but from there how to exit the process and call the JSON? because from there my JSON not working.

I added `"echo "time not match";"` from there I am not able to call the JSON I am getting the output on my network tab.

I am getitng the output

```
enter 1enter 2{"error":true,"msg":"Batch Created"}time not match
```

Would you help me out in this?

```
 $id                         = $this->input->post('venue_id');
    $venue_id                   = implode(',',$id);     
    $activity_list_id           = $this->input->post('activity_name');
    $new_batch_start_date       = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('start_date')));    
    $new_batch_end_date         = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('end_date')));
    $new_batch_start_time       = $this->input->post('start_time');
    $new_batch_end_time         = $this->input->post('end_time');
    $days                       = implode(',',$this->input->post('days'));
    //print_r($days);   

    if($new_batch_start_date >= $new_batch_end_date)
    {
      $response['error'] = false;
      $response['msg']   = "End Date Should be Greater than Start Date";
      echo json_encode($response);
      return false;
    }

    //convert in Time Format
      $new_batch_start_time = strtotime($new_batch_start_time);   
      $new_batch_end_time = strtotime($new_batch_end_time);

      $venue = $this->input->post('name');
      $data = array(      
          'activity_list_id' => $this->input->post('activity_name'),          
          'batch_venue_id'   => $venue_id,      
          'batch_name'       => $this->input->post('batch_name'),     
          'start_date'       => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('start_date'))),     
          'end_date'         => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('end_date'))),     
          'start_time'       => $this->input->post('start_time'),     
          'end_time'         => $this->input->post('end_time'),     
          'total_capacity'   => $this->input->post('total_capecity'),
          'batch_status'     => 1,
          'created_by'       => trim($this->session->userdata['login_data']['user_id']),
          'created_date'     => date('d-m-Y h:i:s A'),
          'batch_days'     => $days
          );


    $get_batch_details = $this->Batch_model->fetchBatches(); 
    if(!empty($get_batch_details))
    {
      foreach ($get_batch_details as $rows)
      {
        $exist_batch_start_date =  $rows->start_date;
        $exist_batch_end_date =  $rows->end_date;
        $batch_time1 =  strtotime($rows->start_time);
        $batch_time2 =  strtotime($rows->end_time);
        $batch_venue_id = explode(',',$rows->batch_venue_id);
        $common_venue_id = array_intersect($id,$batch_venue_id);
        //print_r($common_venue_id);
        if($common_venue_id)
        {
          echo "enter 1";
        //if new batch start date  between existing batch start date 
        if($exist_batch_start_date <= $new_batch_start_date && $exist_batch_end_date >= $new_batch_start_date ){ 

          echo "enter 2";
          if($batch_time1 <= $new_batch_start_time && $batch_time2 > $new_batch_start_time){
                 $msg = "Other Batch Alredy Running On from Date $batch_start_date to $exist_batch_end_date on Time : $batch_time1 to $batch_time2.
                    Please Change Time Slot or Start And End Date"; 
                  $response['error'] = false;
                  $response['msg']   = $msg;
                  echo json_encode($response);
                  exit;
            }
            else{
              $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
              echo "time not match";
              print_r($result);
            }
            break;
      }

     //if date is different 
 else 
    {
      $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
    }    
}else 
    {
      $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
    }
}
}
//first time creating batch
else 
    {
      $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
    }
```

**Mobel**

```
function createBatch($data){
        if($this->db->insert('batch_list',$data))
            {
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['msg']   = "Batch Created";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            else 
            {
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['msg']   = "Failed to Create Batch";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }                   
    }

function fetchBatches()
    {
    $result = $this->db->where(['batch_list.batch_status'=>1,'activity_list.act_status'=>1])
                            ->from('batch_list')
                            ->join('activity_list','activity_list.activity_id = batch_list.activity_list_id')
                            ->get()
                            ->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

**Ajax**

```
success: function(response){
                    var data = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (data.error == true){                        
                        swal({
                             title: "Success", 
                             text: data.msg ,
                             type: "success"
                             }).then(function(){ 
                                location.reload();
                            }
                    );
                    } else {
                        swal({  
                            title: "Warning",                       
                             text: data.msg ,
                             type: "warning"
                            });
                    }
         }
```

Would you help me out in this issue?

Comment: can anyone help me out in this issue?

Comment: post your `fetchBatches` model - i don't see anything in your code where you actually retrieve the start and enddate from your admin...

Comment: @sintakonte, Yes, I updated in the model section. Please check it

Comment: @sintakonte, I am getting the output. even last else condition is also working. even I am gettin the output in the first else but not able to send the JSON to ajax from first and second else

Comment: i don't get it ... i quote you: `then should enter the start date and end date and start time and end time then it will check` where are those dates which admin types in ? you never actually access to that

Comment: @sintakonte, Yes, I updated my whole function. Please check it once

Comment: what is the format of `start_date` and `start_time` ?

Comment: @sintakonte, format is for example 6:00 PM. I am  using like this

Comment: @sintakonte,date time formate is 28-08-2018

Answer (score 0):

your entire approach is a bit messy because you find yourself in a ton of redundant code fragments and nobody is able to understand what exactly you want - i gv you some hints here including an example based on your code

1. **Use Exceptions** - it's perfect for your case - if something goes wrong - stop it
2. Try to filter your need to an extent of **one single task** und try to solve it - and only after that go to the next task
3. Always - remember always - think about one term - if you find **repeatedly the same code** in your application - you know something is wrong - and **you should refactor it** - don't be ashamed about redundancies - they do always happen - but if you find them, you must refactor those code snippets

Now to your example

What are your tasks here ?

- you can try to ask your database if a batch is already running - you dont need to iterate over the entire table entries
- Compare both input Dates from Administrator - if start date is in the future of end date, instantely stop the application
- your intersection isn't really clear to me what you want to achieve here - but i'm really convinced you can ask the database here too (catchword: `find_in_set`)

Based on that information we can start to develop things now ;) (if i don't have everything just complete the list above and try to implement your task)

**Controller:**

```
try
{
    $id = $this->input->post('venue_id');
    $venue_id = implode(',',$id);     
    $activity_list_id = $this->input->post('activity_name');
    $new_batch_start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('start_date')));    
    $new_batch_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('end_date')));
    $new_batch_start_time = $this->input->post('start_time');
    $new_batch_end_time = $this->input->post('end_time');
    $days = implode(',',$this->input->post('days'));

    $objDateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i a', $new_batch_start_date.' '.$new_batch_start_time);
    $objDateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i a', $new_batch_end_date.' '.$new_batch_end_time);

    if ($objDateEnd < $objDateStart)    throw new Exception('End Date Should be Greater than Start Date');

    if ($this->Batch_model->hasBatchesBetweenDates($objDateStart, $objDateEnd)) throw new Exception('Other Batch already running On from '.$objDateStart->format('d-m-Y H:i').' to '.$objDateEnd->format('d-m-Y H:i').'. Please Change Time Slot for Start and End Date'); 

    $data = array(      
        'activity_list_id' => $this->input->post('activity_name'),          
        'batch_venue_id'   => $venue_id,      
        'batch_name'       => $this->input->post('batch_name'),     
        'start_date'       => $objDateStart->format('Y-m-d'),     
        'end_date'         => $objDateEnd->format('Y-m-d'),     
        'start_time'       => $objDateStart->format('H:i'),     
        'end_time'         => $objDateEnd->format('H:i'),     
        'total_capacity'   => $this->input->post('total_capecity'),
        'batch_status'     => 1,
        'created_by'       => trim($this->session->userdata['login_data']['user_id']),
        'created_date'     => date('d-m-Y h:i:s A'),
        'batch_days'     => $days
    );

    $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $arrError = [
        'error' => false,
        'msg' => $e->getMessage()
    ];

    echo json_encode($arrError);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function hasBatchesBetweenDates(DateTime $objDateStart, DateTime $objDateEnd)
{
    $query = $this->db
    ->from('batch_list')
    ->join('activity_list','activity_list.activity_id = batch_list.activity_list_id')
    ->where('CONCAT(start_date,\' \',start_time)  >=', $objDateStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->or_group_start()
        ->where('CONCAT(end_date, \' \', end_time) <=', $objDateEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('CONCAT(end_date, \' \', end_time) >=', $objDateStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->group_end()
    ->get();

    return ($query->num_rows() > 0);
}
```

i hope you understand the concepts here - if you've questions - don't hesitate to ask

Comment: give me sometime to implement this.

Comment: realy appriciate your effects,Yes, It's working but not 100% because I added the the code in my question.     $batch_venue_id = explode(',',$rows->batch_venue_id);
        $common_venue_id = array_intersect($id,$batch_venue_id); from the database to check.  and I am checking the  $common_venue_id.  why $common_venue because I can choose the different venue on the same date. We can't choose the same venue on the same date and time.

Comment: Let me explain, I have a venue UK in the database from 14-08-18 to 20-08-18. Now I choose INDIA and date 14-08-18 to 20-08-18. it's should create it. because my venu id is different.

Comment: if the $common_venue id is same and date is also the same but time is different then the batch list can create. For example, a common id is 1 and the date is 15-08-2018 and time is 6:00 am to 8:00 am is already in the database. if admin select common id 1 and date  15-08-2018 but time should be different like 8:00 am to 10:00 am. Admin can't create if time is 6:00 am to 8:00am

Comment: any more help in this?

Comment: are you even familiar with mysql ? I gv you a pretty neat tutorial how to do things, because i thought you are a hardworker and want to understand things ..., your request shouldn't be that hard to implement because i also gave you already a hint - take a look at the mysql built in function `find_in_set` and you should be able to achieve what you want

Comment: and if you want any further help - you should give some example data of your venue_id and how this does look - and furthermore an example from your database with some sample data (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post) - otherwise its pretty hard to help you ... (btw. just because i don't write your entire code for you it doesn't mean this answer isn't helpful - @least you can do an upvote, or accept it because this is a pretty nice gems and there is a ton of work in it, and should help you in any way for your future...

Comment: is this an integer oder a varchar ? because in your code i thought this is a comma separated list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178183/discussion-between-user9437856-and-sintakonte).