# How to check multiple value in if condition

Tags: php

Is it right way for check $orderstatus value??

```
if($orderstatus == Refund || Cancel){

            }
```

i want  to if orderstatus is refund or cancle then and then only go to if condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP If Statement with Multiple Conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593512/php-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if($orderstatus == 'Refund' || $orderstatus == 'Cancel'){
    //got here
}
```

This checks for either condition.

Also, I added quotes around the `Refund` and `cancel` values because they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also in_array

```
if($orderstatus == 'Refund' || $orderstatus == 'Cancel'){

}
```

or

```
if (in_array($orderstatus, array('Refund', 'Cancel'))) {

}
```