# Compress multiple OR-conditions in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to allow users to write a value into **Cell A1**.

```
Sub TestUsername()
If Environ("Username") = "firstname1.lastname1" Or Environ("Username") = "firstname2.lastname2" _
Or Environ("Username") = "firstname3.lastname3" Or Environ("Username") = "firstname4.lastname4" Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see I list each user who is allowed to enter a value into **Cell A1** with an `OR-condition` in my VBA code. All this works fine.

---

Now, I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this. Something like this:

```
Sub TestUsername()
If List of or-conditions: {"firstname1.lastname1", "firstname2.lastname2", _
"firstname3.lastname3", "firstname4.lastname4"} = True Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```

I just know in PHP you can compress multiple conditions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593512/php-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions). Therefore, I thought this might also be possible for VBA programming.

Comment: Select Case might be a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
Sub TestUsername()
    Select Case Environ("Username")
    Case "firstname1.lastname1", "firstname2.lastname2", "firstname3.lastname3"
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
    Case Else
        Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, if you had an atrocious amount of conditions, you could stick them in an array and then simply replace your conditional statement

```
If Environ("Username") = "firstname1.lastname1" Or Environ("Username") = "firstname2.lastname2" _
Or Environ("Username") = "firstname3.lastname3" Or Environ("Username") = "firstname4.lastname4" Then
```

with this

```
If IsInArray(Environ("Username"), arr) Then
```

This does require that you dimension an array with the conditions first and use this function, however:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

This way, your code becomes much more readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working in a cell, you might want to define the allowed usernames within the spreadsheet.

Here's how the spreadsheet table might look:

[image: spreadsheet]

And here's the code you might use:

```
Sub TestUsername()
    Dim username As String
    Dim userInTable As Integer
    Dim allowedUserRange As Excel.Range

    username = Environ("username")
    Set allowedUserRange = Excel.Range("tUsers")

    userInTable = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(allowedUserRange, username)

    If userInTable Then
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
    Else
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't think this really answers the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

The Select Case provides a great solution to testing multiple conditions at the same time. I am using this to alert the user when they have not furnished all the required inputs. I am monitoring inputs from a number of Drop Down Boxes as well as some direct cell inputs.

```
Select Case True 
  Case Range("Customer_DD_Control_Cell") > 0 _ 
    And Range("Dealer_DD_Control_Cell") > 0 _ 
    And Range("Rep_DD_Control_Cell") > 0 _ 
    And Range("Product_DD_Control_Cell") > 0 _ 
    And Len(Range("Customer_State_Input")) > 0 _ 
    And Len(Range("Contract_Date_Input")) > 0
Case Else
 MsgBox "You have not completed the required inputs" 
End Select
```