# How to make an if check with four cases

Tags: php

I want to add another option to the following "if" condition, so it checks for four cases instead of three that it checks for now.

The option I want to add is

```
$chauffeur_data['enable-pos'];
```

and if check is valid then `$pos_check` should be '1'.

This is for the second step in the booking process in this page https://gr.transfer4u.eu and i want when the payment option "Pay with Card on POS in the Car" is checked, the booking to complete. Now it does not.

```
<?php
if ($chauffeur_data['enable-paypal'] == '1') {

    $paypal_check = '1';
    $stripe_check = '0';
    $cash_check = '0';
    $pos_check = '0';
} elseif ($chauffeur_data['enable-paypal'] == '0' && $chauffeur_data['enable-stripe'] == '1') {

    $paypal_check = '0';
    $stripe_check = '1';
    $cash_check = '0';
    $pos_check = '0';
} elseif ($chauffeur_data['enable-stripe'] == '0' && $chauffeur_data['enable-cash'] == '1') {

    $paypal_check = '0';
    $stripe_check = '0';
    $cash_check = '1';
    $pos_check = '0';
} else {

    $paypal_check = '0';
    $stripe_check = '0';
    $cash_check = '0';
    $pos_check = '1';
}
```

So, the code above is wrong as I don't see the success booking message when I check the "Pay with Card on POS in the Car" and proceed. How should be the correct code?

Comment: concatenate the clauses with && (and) or || (or). Brackets might be neccessary...

Comment: That's not really complicated code - what have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP If Statement with Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593512/php-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with slight modification. Hope it will work

```
<?php
$paypal_check = 0;
$stripe_check = 0;
$cash_check = 0;
$pos_check = 0;
if ($chauffeur_data['enable-paypal'] == 1) {

  $paypal_check = 1;
} elseif ($chauffeur_data['enable-stripe'] == 1) {

  $stripe_check = 1;
} elseif ($chauffeur_data['enable-cash'] == 1) {

  $cash_check = 1;
} elseif ($chauffeur_data['enable-pos'] == 1) {

  $pos_check = 1;
} else {
  $pos_check = 1;
}
```

If the above code do not work for you, Please add a bit more details of your problem

Comment: I used your code but still don't get a succesful booking message. Seems that something is missing and it doesn't take me to the next step. When I check any of the other three payment methods, it completes succesfully, though. I attach the whole php file. Maybe i am missing some information that are needed upon submit for the next step to complete. https://pastebin.com/ui9CYh4G
Your code starts at line 256.