# WooCommerce: Disable multiple Payment methods based on country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, payment-method

What I am trying to do here is hide payments methods, based on the customer country.

- Hide bacs and cheque, when the country is different than US.
- When the country is US, hide cod payment method (this is working)

I been trying to do this, but it didn't work

Here is the code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'custom_payment_gateway_disable_country' );
  
function custom_payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['bacs' && 'cheque'] ) && WC()->customer->get_billing_country() <> 'US' ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['bacs' && 'cheque'] );
    } else {
        if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && WC()->customer->get_billing_country() == 'US' ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

---

Can someone push me in the right direction? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: your payment method name is like "bacs and cheque" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if/else statements are wrong. As `isset( $available_gateways['bacs' && 'cheque']` will never work.

See: [PHP If Statement with Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593512/php-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $payment_gateways ) {
    // Not on admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways;

    // Get country
    $customer_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() : WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    
    // Country = US
    if ( in_array( $customer_country, array( 'US' ) ) ) {       
        // Cod
        if ( isset( $payment_gateways['cod'] ) ) {
            unset( $payment_gateways['cod'] );
        }
    } else {
        // Bacs & Cheque
        if ( isset( $payment_gateways['bacs'] ) && isset( $payment_gateways['cheque'] ) ) {
            unset( $payment_gateways['bacs'] );
            unset( $payment_gateways['cheque'] );
        }       
    }
    
    return $payment_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```